# keyof does not extract named keys of interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working with some typescript interfaces that I don't have much control over. I'm trying to extract the keys of an interface I do control, but that must extend one that I don't control. The structure is basically this:

```js
// interface I don't control
interface T1 {
  [key: string]: string
}

// interface I control that must extend T1
interface T2 extends T1 {
  a: string
  b: string
}

// my attempt to extract "a" | "b" from T2
type T3 = keyof T2
```

In this case, `T3` evaluates to `string | number` instead of `"a" | "b"`. Removing `extends T1` gives me what I want, but I can't do that for 'reasons'. Is there a way to get a type that is just the named keys of `T2`?

Comment: Can't you just make an interface that DOESN'T extend T1 and extract those keys? Because keys of `[key: string]: string` is every possible string.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković It's a contrived example, but the purpose is to restrict the type of the properties of `T2`.

Comment: if T1 interface  has non specific signature like this: ```[key: string]: string``` then there is not much value extending T2 before extracting values. If T1 actually has specific properties then T3 should actually work for example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBJUATA9pAOTSioHTx4A2AUFHEmhgCoCMoA3jaKMgFygAzhSgBzbqABGA4fDE0AvjRogIMBCnRZS5SlVDQAFshIBbAK7DQsAB5xIOUGzrrGW5gCZOE-kJGRxHmk-OQCJVBl-cSUVMFMAT15oOFMABxJoPGs7eDQSACJkfNAAH1B8yWLESlMnDxpoeNSWAGZQAF5QAGtYeLxEOuUySCtEPDwBZjaO0EJJQhogA

Comment: @ZZB That makes sense, but what if I want to also restrict `b` in `T2` to `string` instead of `number`? How can I build a composite interface that has those required keys from `T2` and force them to be `string` if I remove `extends T1`?

Comment: @itslittlejohn is this what you are looking for? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwM4HlkBsQB4AVKCAD2AmQBN0oBDZEAPigF4oBvKAbQGsIQUFFH4gA9gDMohALoAuKOgQpUAXwBQ60JGkBGNrGVosuAhzoKlSNAG4oAI0tG1LTduija7UZL2agA

Comment: @ZZB more like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBJUATA9pAOTSioHTx4A2AUFHEmhgCoCMoA3jaKANoDWsAJ4AuUAGcKUAOYBdMZPgyaAXxo0QEGAhTospcpSqhoAC2QkAtgFdJoWAA84kHKDZ1tjPcwBMnbqDIClKQ0gEARsFKoarq9DpMbgDM9k6wLuJuPgA0buwcahpglkKB0HCWAA4k0HipFGgkAETITaAAPqBN4W2IlJZZNNBClRgA0sKZALyggkJ4iIM0ZJB20GLMKTNcPDxBoITIhNkBPJEH4YSxQA

Comment: @itslittlejohn not sure what is the problem then, the code you provided does extract keys correctly. It doesn't print them in the intellisense but assignments do error out https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBJUATA9pAOTSioHTx4A2AUFHEmhgCoCMoA3jaKANoDWsAJ4AuUAGcKUAOYBdMZPgyaAXxo0QEGAhTospcpSqhoAC2QkAtgFdJoWAA84kHKDZ1tjPcwBMnbqDIClKQ0gEARsFKoarq9DpMbgDM9k6wLuJuPgA0buwcahpglkKB0HCWAA4k0HipFGgkAETITaAAPqBN4W2IlJZZNNBClRgA0sKZALyggkJ4iINFZPDwsKjQNGSQdnCSYhNC06CEyITqIAiU8FsEu7CSPgeToDOEqOe3OzVizCkzXB4PCCJzO2QCPEiJ3ChHBaiAA